# Creating a Jquery selector Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Dear I would like to load a table data dynamically using JSON format data coming from a PHP file. I have tried the following one and I don't see any data displayed in the table.

```
function loadTable() {
    $.getJSON( 'sort.php', function( data ) {
        $.each( data, function( i, val ) {
            $('#most_active tr:eq(i)').after(
                '<tr>'+
                    '<td>'+val.value1+'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+val.value2+'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+val.value3'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+val.data+'</td>'+
                '</tr>'
            );
        });
    });
}
```

If I try this second one using 0 instead of 'i' I get all the values but in the wrong order, the last in the JSON become the first in the table.

```
function loadTable() {
    $.getJSON( 'sort.php', function( data ) {
        $.each( data, function( i, val ) {
            $('#most_active tr:eq(0)').after(
                '<tr>'+
                    '<td>'+val.value1+'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+val.value2+'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+val.value3'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+val.data+'</td>'+
                '</tr>'
            );
        });
    });
}
```

Any suggestion to retrieve and fill the table properly and in the same order of JSON vector?

Thanks

The code part related to the table

```
<table id="most_activeAP" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Value</th>
            <th>Value</th>
            <th>Time</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I've retagged your question as JavaScript since you don't seem to be asking anything about PHP.

Comment: post some of your data, or at the very least its exact structure.

Comment: You could use the [datatables](http://datatables.net/) plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're best off using the .eq() function

```
function loadTable() {
    $.getJSON( 'sort.php', function( data ) {
        $.each( data, function( i, val ) {
            $('#most_active tr').eq(i).after(
                '<tr>'+
                    '<td>'+val.value1+'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+val.value2+'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+val.value3'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+val.data+'</td>'+
                '</tr>'
            );
        });
    });
}
```

That also means that you can build your element list once and reuse it:

```
function loadTable() {
    $.getJSON( 'sort.php', function( data ) {
        var $mostActiveRows = $('#most_active tr');
        $.each( data, function( i, val ) {      
            $mostActiveRows.eq(i).after(
                '<tr>'+
                    '<td>'+val.value1+'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+val.value2+'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+val.value3'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+val.data+'</td>'+
                '</tr>'
            );
        });
    });
}
```

That second version will be a bit more efficient (a bit less wasteful).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried creating the selector as below...

```
function loadTable()
{
    $.getJSON( 'sort.php', function( data )
    {
        $.each( data, function( i, val )
        {
            $('#most_active tr:eq(' + i + ')').after('<tr><td>'+val.value1+'</td><td>'+val.value2+'</td><td>'+val.value3'</td><td>'+val.data+'</td></tr>');
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, it works. Was my mistake I forgot to manage 'i' as variable